# Vue 3 directive handler not working as basic directives

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-directives

I've created a directive but I can't get it to work with a "executed" handler:
Here is how the directive is created:

```js
vueApp.directive('click-outside', {
            beforeMount(el, binding, vnode) {
                el.clickOutsideEvent = (evt) => {
                    evt.stopPropagation();
                    if (!(el === evt.target || el.contains(evt.target))) {
                        binding.value(evt, el);
                    }
                }
                // Wait 1 frame otherwise a potential click that mounted the element will immediately trigger a click-outside event:
                window.requestAnimationFrame(() => { document.addEventListener('click', el.clickOutsideEvent) });
            },
            unmounted(el) {
                document.removeEventListener('click', el.clickOutsideEvent);
            },
        });
```

If I add a handler like for example `close` will work (the close function will be called):

```html
<div v-if="opened" v-click-outside="close">
    Some content
</div>
```

But if I use a bit of script it fails:

```html
<div v-if="opened" v-click-outside="opend = false">
    Some content
</div>
```

or

```html
<div v-if="opened" v-click-outside="close()">
    Some content
</div>
```

These give me an error: `Uncaught TypeError: binding.value is not a function`

This behavior works for e.g. a @click directive `@click="opened = !opened"` or `@click="open()"`
So the question is if and how can I change the directive so it works in all cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike `v-bind`, the binding value of your directive is evaluated immediately upon rendering the template. `@vue/compiler-sfc` transforms expressions in the `v-bind` value into a function, but you have to manually do that for your custom directive:

```html
<div v-if="opened" v-click-outside="() => opened = false">
    Some content                    
</div>
```

```html
<div v-if="opened" v-click-outside="() => close()">
    Some content                    
</div>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-bind-function-value-for-directive?file=src/main.js)

Comment: Ah, thanks. It makes a bit more sense now :)
No way to trick the compiler into doing this for custom directives as well?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of